# Firefox in cache slowing down phone

Tags: firefox-for-android, cache, swap

I am running Cyanogenmod on my rather old Motorola Droid 4, and it is pretty slow by now. I something quite strange lately. From what I read on the internet Android seems to handle memory quite differently than Windows or a regular Linux would. From what I understand it keeps apps that I closed or put into the background in the memory so they start up faster. This can be observed when going to Settings->Apps->Active->Apps in Cache. Apps in the cache should not be really running and should get cleared out as soon as active apps require the storage. But when I have Firefox in cache this doesn't seem to work. Firefox uses quite a lot of memory (top tells me it's using around 800mb, while Android still reports some 150-300mb, my phone has 1GB RAM total) and while it is in cache the whole phone slows to a crawl. Top tells me, that my CPU is hardly used, so it looks just like heavy swapping.
If I kill Firefox my phone instantly speeds up.

I checked using busybox free that I don't have swapping enabled.

Does anyone know the reason behind that or even a way to fix that issue?